# Can the sum of a convergent sequence and a divergent sequence converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can the sum of a convergent sequence and a divergent sequence converge ? I don't think so. How to prove it ?

Answer (score 6):

HINT: The difference of two convergent series is convergent.

Comment: Prove by contradiction!